# Load a resource in Jar

Tags: java, freemarker

Below is structure of my `Jar` file

```
root
 - template.ftl
 - org.project.myproject.App.java
```

Inside App.java, I have a line of code that expects me to specify the `directory` for loading the `template.ftl`. Something like:

```
Line#1: cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading("java.io.File object that represents /directory/for/storing/template/files");
```

and the next line of code, read the template file

```
Line#2: Template temp = cfg.getTemplate("template.ftl");
```

My problem is that I'm not able to specify the path of directory from where the file will be loaded. The template file to load is available in root of the `Jar`. When I write,

```
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("."));
```

It says, `template.ftl` not found.

What should be apprpriate code that can set the template directory correctly at `Line#1` above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this isn't working for you because you're trying to load a file that doesn't exist as a file but is inside your jar. To read your template as an input stream from within the jar file you could do:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("template.ftl");
```

I think this should help get you onto the right track.

Comment: Template temp = cfg.getTemplate("template.ftl"); .. This line expects to specify the file path.

Comment: URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("template.ftl");
File file = new File(url.toURI()); ... that might do the trick

Comment: Yep.. This is exactly what I derived out of your answer too. Thanks much for detail.

Comment: Or this might work... URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(""); File file = new File(url.toURI()); cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(file); ... I'm just throwing things out there now

Answer (score 0):

```
Line#2: Template temp = cfg.getTemplate("/template.ftl");
```