# Including Images with an executable jar

Tags: java, image, jar, embedded-resource, javax.imageio

I have been browsing Stackoverflow all day looking for how to do this and I have not been successful yet

I am packaging a quick game I made into a executable jar but I didnt reference the images correctly I just referenced the files

```
background = ImageIO.read(new File("wood.jpeg"));
```

I have my classes in src default package 
Im not sure where I should add the images or if I have to add it to the build path
or correct way of adding the images to the build path in the newest version of eclipse

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Files in a Jar are not files in the sense of a file on disk.  They are simply a (possibly) compressed stream of bytes.

Java makes it easy to extract these "resources" from Jar files through the use of the `ClassLoader`

```
background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/wood.jpeg"));
```

Should work...

This will return a `URL` which `ImageIO` can use to load the resource.

You could also have a read of

- [Classpath resource within jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900154/classpath-resource-within-jar)
- [Jar get image as resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163012/jar-get-image-as-resource)
- [Load a resource in Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408981/load-a-resource-in-jar)

And I could list some more.  So, yeah, it gets asked a lot ;)

Comment: +1 Very simple explanation, but you should also mention where the images should go in a project. e.g. src/main/resources for maven to pick up.

Comment: See also the [embedded-resource info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

Comment: @asgs I feel that point goes beyond the question.  With the right build file/circumstances, we can *generate* images at build-time.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Right, just wanted to let the OP know that there's a commonly used directory dedicated for resources. @-MadProgrammer Yes, that's a quick example.

Comment: I got this to work but only after dragging the image files into the bin folder although I have not been able to launch the execuatble jar since.. Thank you!

Comment: correction I added the files to the bin for proof on concept to see if it would work after that I added the images to a source folder so they are added automatically to the bin and the jar it works fine in windows but when I run it on linux I get my program with no images again

Comment: @Mintybacon try printing the results of `getClass().getResource("/wood.jpeg")` to the console (using `System.out.println`) to verify that the image was found within the Jar resource. Technically, if it worked on one platform, this approach should work on others

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Constructing Runnable Jar` using the Eclipse.

```
R_Click on the Project in the Package Explorer ---> 
Export ---> Runnable JAR file ---> 
Select the option of Package required libraries into generated JAR
```

Comment: This option refers to libraries rather than resources, and it does not address the problem of attempting to load the zip entry as if it were a `File`.