# How do I save images onto a program for Java?

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource

For my final project I want to use images for my othello game that I am making. Is there any way for me to save the images onto my program so that I do not have to download it separately and upload it? Sorry this is my first year programming so I am a beginner.

Edit:
[Screenshot of my current 'board' for the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HghMp.png)

I wanted to add the pictures into the buttons on the board to indicate an empty spot, a black piece, and a white piece.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? 'Download' and 'Upload' where? What images are you trying to save? How does this fit in with the game?

Comment: Store the images inside the Jar file, then use `Class#getResource` to load them

Comment: I wanted to upload images of board pieces to recreate the board. Specifically, I wanted to have the images in buttons. Sorry I will edit the post to make it clearer. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including Images with an executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488836/including-images-with-an-executable-jar)